# Swift: Updating labels in shared container view

Tags: ios, swift, containers

Context:

I have three ViewControllers that share one Container View. The ContainerViewController holds a variable that will be modified, for example, a bank.

I have a button that adds 10000 to the bank. It adds 10000 to the bank when clicked though it is only displayed if you navigate to another tab or come back.

[image]

---

[image]

I've been researching this issue and seem to understand that I need to use prepare(for segue:) to update it but I can't seem to get it to work.

Problem: How can I update the container view(since I would like additional labels in there eventually) immediately so the new value is reflected and displayed on the same VC?

HomeViewController (w/button)

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func bankButton(_ sender: Any) {

        bank += 10099
        print("\(bank)")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "container" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController

       }
       }

    }

}
```

ViewController (Container)

```
var bank = 10000;

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var cashLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        cashLabel.text = "\(bank)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many answers, for example, RxSwift can help you, or something more easy, like a Notification Center. both work with observers, I hope that this code can help you.

add this code in your container view

```
var bank = 10000
viewDidLoad(){
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateLabel(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateLabel"), object: nil)
}

@objc func updateLabel(_ notification: Notification){
    if let data = notification.object as? Int{
    bank += data
    cashLabel.text = "\(bank)"
    }
}
```

now, add this code in your main view controller

```
@IBAction func bankButton(_ sender: Any) {
    bank += 10099
    print("\(bank)")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateLabel"), object: bank)
}
```

I recommend you research about RxSwift, and combine, the latter only works on iOS 13

Comment: Thank you! I get an error that NSNotification.Name has no member 'didReceiveData'. I will read definitely read up on RxSwift.